# Limit the data set of a single table within a multi-table sql select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, join, rownum

I'm working in an Oracle environment.

In a 1:M table relationship I want to write a query that will bring me each row from the "1" table and **only 1 matching row** from the "many" table.

To give a made up example... ( * = Primary Key/Foreign Key )

```
EMPLOYEE
*emp_id
name
department

PHONE_NUMBER
*emp_id
num
```

There are **many** phone numbers for **one** employee.

Let's say I wanted to return all employees and **only one** of their phone numbers. (Please forgive the far-fetched example. I'm trying to simulate a workplace scenario)

I tried to run:

```
SELECT emp.*, phone.num
FROM EMPLOYEE emp
JOIN PHONE_NUMBER phone
    ON emp.emp_id = phone.emp_id
WHERE phone.ROWNUM <= 1;
```

It turns out (and it makes sense to me now) that ROWNUM only exists within the context of the results returned from the entire query. There is not a "ROWNUM" for each table's data set.

I also tried:

```
SELECT emp.*, phone.num
FROM EMPLOYEE emp
JOIN PHONE_NUMBER phone
    ON emp.emp_id = phone.emp_id
WHERE phone.num = (SELECT MAX(num)
                   FROM PHONE_NUMBER);
```

That one just returned me one row total. I wanted the inner SELECT to run once for **each** row in EMPLOYEE.

I'm not sure how else to think about this. I basically want my result set to be the number of rows in the EMPLOYEE table and for each row the **first** matching row in the PHONE_NUMBER table.

Obviously there are all sorts of ways to do this with procedures and scripts and such but I feel like there is a single-query solution in there somewhere...

Any ideas?

Comment: Oracle also has a function which will merge the phone numbers to one column if you do a group by

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! P.S. Isn't anyone gonna +1 my question? :( New guy trying to gain some privileges... :)

Comment: Hey, thanks, mysterious plus-oner! Ask and ye shall receive... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one phone number, then use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT e.*, p.num
FROM EMPLOYEE emp JOIN
     (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id) as seqnum
      FROM PHONE_NUMBER p
     ) p
    ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id and seqnum = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use aggregation, to get the minimum or maximum value.

Comment: This is the one! Ties don't matter and I don't care about the order. I had to look into analytic functions for a few days to understand what this was doing. (I'm compelled to learn to fish not just chow down!) Not only did this solve my problem but I learned a new SQL concept. Thank you, Gordon!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `rank` (or `dense_rank` or `row_number` depending on how you want to handle ties)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT emp.*, 
               phone.num, 
               rank() over (partition by emp.emp_id
                                order by phone.num) rnk
          FROM EMPLOYEE emp
               JOIN PHONE_NUMBER phone
                 ON emp.emp_id = phone.emp_id)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

will rank the rows in `phone` for each `emp_id` by `num` and return the top row.  If there could be two rows for the same `emp_id` with the same `num`, `rank` would assign both a `rnk` of 1 so you'd get duplicate rows.  You could add additional conditions to the `order by` to break the tie.  Or you could use `row_number` rather than `rank` to arbitrarily break the tie.

Answer (score 2):

All above answers will work beautifully with the scenario you described.

But if you have some employees which are missing in phone tables, then you need to do a left outer join like below. (I faced similar scenario where I needed isolated parents also)

```
EMP
---------
emp_id Name
---------
 1   AA
 2   BB
 3   CC

PHONE
----------
emp_id no

1   7555
1   7777
2   5555


select emp.emp_id,ph.no from emp left outer join
(
select emp_id,no,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id) as rnum
  FROM phone) ph
on emp.emp_id = ph.emp_id
  where ph.rnum = 1 or ph.rnum is null

Result
EMP_ID  NO
  1    7555
  2    5555
  3   (null)
```

Comment: Great point. I wouldn't need that in my actual business case but outer joins are always important. They took me an irritatingly long time to fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. Simple but maybe wont scale well for lot of columns.

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6245fe/7)

```
select e.emp_id, e.name, e.dep, min(p.phone_num)
from 
    EMPLOYEE e inner join
    PHONE_NUMBER p on e.emp_id = p.emp_id
group by e.emp_id, e.name, e.dep
order by e.emp_id;
```

And this fix the query you try

[**Sql Fiddle 2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6245fe/5)

```
SELECT emp.*, phone.num
FROM EMPLOYEE emp
    JOIN PHONE_NUMBER phone
    ON emp.emp_id = phone.emp_id
WHERE phone.num = (SELECT MAX(num)
                   FROM PHONE_NUMBER p
                   WHERE p.emp_id = emp.emp_id );
```